# Why do some functions of ''r'' not work with the pipe (%>%), as is the case with ''unique()''?

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

Goodnight everyone.
Why do some functions of ''r'' not work with the pipe (`%>%`), as is the case with `unique()`?.

For example, if I run an object named `GOT` as follows:

```
GOT %>%
unique(region)
```

This does not give me results, but if I do it in the following way:

```
unique(GOT$region)
```

the results are displayed.
That doesn't happen with other functions like `select()` or `arrange()`. For what is this? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The pipe operator passes the left hand side into the first argument of the function in the right hand side (unless specified otherwise). In that sense, it works with every function, including `unique`.

But, not every function works like the dplyr functions you mentioned. `select` and `arrange` are part of dplyr/(tidyverse), and, as many other function in that (group of) package(s): they (1) have the first argument as a dataframe; and (2) allow you to refer to a column only by its name in the other arguments.

`unique` is from base R, and it has none of the two characteristics above. As the default usage of `unique` is `unique(x, incomparables = FALSE, ...)`, you're doing `unique('GOT, incomparables = region, ...)`, so that column name isn't being passed onto an argument that can comprehend it.

If you really want to use a pipe, you can do:

- `GOT %>% {unique(.$region)}`
- `GOT %>% pull(region) %>% unique()` as @Curt F. added
- `GOT %>% with(region) %>% unique()` as @Ric Villalba added

Comment: I use `unique()` with the pipe all the time.  I would do something like `GOT %>% pull(region) %>% unique()`

Comment: Another way : `GOT %>% with(unique(region))`

Comment: Yes, the problem is thinking that `unique` works the same way as dplyr functions and thus passing a dataframe to it. I'll make that clearer in my answer, thanks!

Comment: I think it's incorrect to say that `unique` is not made to work directly with data.frames, as it most certainly is and will farm out to `unique.data.frame` if passed a data.frame as the x=argument. It's not made to work with a piped `data=` argument, but that's something different entirely. E.g. - `mtcars %>% select(cyl, gear) %>% unique()` gives all the unique combinations of the two variables cyl and gear.

Comment: `dplyr::distinct()` is the `tidyverse` version of `unique()`, ex: `iris %>% distinct(Species)`

Comment: @thelatemail true, i chose a poor phrasing. I edited my answer.

Comment: All good - i'd already upvoted as it was good info apart from that nitpick :-)